# How to update choice of select input in r shiny dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app where the choices of select input should update dynamically based earlier inputs.

For example if both category and segment are selected in 1st input widgets and only skin_care in 2nd input widgets then Medicated and Non medicated 
should come as option in 3rd input widgets not all the unique names of segment. 
If hair_care slected instead of skin_care in 2nd input widgets then Gents and Ladies should be choice in 3rd input widgets dropdown.
So basically the choice to select from drop down is dependent on what user seleted on earlier input widgets. Same goes for brand also.
Here I am assuming the seletcion of dimension is always from left to right.

The actual app will ask user to load data and it can have 10 dimensions or may be more.I kept three for simplicity.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Data", fluid = TRUE,
         sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(p("Please remove None first"),
                        uiOutput("dim"),
                        uiOutput("levels1")),
           mainPanel(
             DT::dataTableOutput("data_display")
           ))))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

# creating Data 
data <- reactive({
data <-  data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2018-05-25","2018-05-26")),
            category = c(rep("skin_care",6),rep("hair_care",6)),
            Segment =  c(rep("Medicated",4),rep("Non_Medicated",2),
                       rep("Ladies",4),rep("Gents",2)),
            Brand = c("X","X","Y","Y","Z","Z","A","A","B","B","C","C"),
            sales = round(rnorm(12,100,3)))
})


# Displaying Data  

output$data_display <- DT::renderDataTable(                    
datatable(data(),options = list(pageLength = 12),rownames = FALSE)
)

# selects dimension (Only character variable to be selected)

output$dim<-renderUI({
b<-colnames(data()[sapply(data(),class)=="character"])
selectInput("x","Select only character variable",choices = 
              c("NONE",b[1:length(b)]),selected="NONE",multiple = TRUE)
 })

 #  user selects levels of dimension 

output$levels1<-renderUI({
if(is.null(input$x)){
  return(NULL)
}
else if(sum(input$x=="NONE")==1){
  return(NULL)
}
else{
  lapply(seq(input$x),function(i){
    selectInput(inputId = paste0("range",i),
                paste0("Select level of ",input$x[i]),
                choices = c(unique(data()[,input$x[i]]),"ALL"),multiple = TRUE)

   })
  }
 })
 })
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**EDIT:** Provided option in dropdown in dynamically appearing selectinput widgets

Comment: Use observe... observe will react to every input$ variable not isolated..

Comment: could you clarify what the user menu (ui) should do? should it be a drilldown? Like you choose category and then a new dropdown with skin_care and hair_care pops up? Or is it supposed to be an if-else-thing? Like if you choose `category` and `brand` then you can only choose brands with skin care products? Your wording is not clear. Edit the question. Make shorter sentences. Enumerate if possible. Thank you

Comment: @ 5th Yes,it is like drilldown. If both category and brand name  are selected in 1st input widget then both skin_care and hair_care will be an option and  user can select either one or both. If only skin_care or hair_care is selected then corresponding brand name should be an option in 3rd dropdown not all the brand names.

Comment: I've used multiple `uiOutput` statements in my `ui` part with the corresponding `renderUI` statement in `server`. The `renderUI` uses reactive objects and `input` to display the correct options in `selectInput` menus. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Gautam No, Multiple uiOutput will be a challenge if there are many character variable. Side bar will be then filled with many input widgets. I want to make it dynamic If user want any dimension then only further dropdowns will come.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: If in the 1st dropdown one input is chosen. You only want to have a second dropdown to choose e.g. `skin_care` or `health_care` if category is chosen? No third dropdown, right?

Comment: @ 5th,You have got the gist! The variables will not always be two it can be n number of dimensions.I kept two for simplicity.To overcome these lapply function is used. The challenge is how to update the choices of dynamically appearing input widgets based on what user selected in earlier input widgets assuming there are n dimensions?

Comment: @joy_1379 check out my answer below. I explained why making this for n-dimensions is a ver bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the code you provided. This answer may seem incomplete, but I believe it is the best way to solve your questions. Lets go through it:

1. In the ui-part I added another `uiOutput`-wrapper called `level3` (which only returns a dropdown if more than one input is selected in the very first dropdown)
2. Subsequently I added another `renderUI` in the server-part
3. I moved the `DT`-table to the end of the server part
4. I added a complete set of if-else conditions to the `levels1`-object in the server-part (too complex to explain, just try them out)
5. I also added a complete set of if-else-conditions to check whether the ui works

However I don't see how I can keep my code generic in my answer. I mean if you have multiple columns it might be easier to just make a dropdown for each column. Seems easier to me.

The *main problem* is that you can't guess *which element the user will select first* in the first dropdown. Therefore you would need to go through all possible combinations. Which is nuts if you have much more than two variables. In any case because you know the data 
you know better than me, if the extra programming effort is worth the time. If you don't believe me, use my code, try generalising the code, use i.e., five character columns and then comment below what you learned.

Last but not least I often used `grep` to subset the data. If you combine this with a `paste` and `collapse='|'` it match each occasion of your character vector.

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", fluid = TRUE,
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(uiOutput("dim"),
                            uiOutput("levels1"),
                            uiOutput("level3")),
               mainPanel(
                 DT::dataTableOutput("data_display")
               ))))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  # creating Data 
  data <- reactive({
    data <-  data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2018-05-25","2018-05-26")),
                        category = c(rep("skin_care",6),rep("hair_care",6)),
                        Brand = c("X","X","Y","Y","Z","Z","A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                        sales = round(rnorm(12,100,3)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })




  # selects dimension (Only character variable to be selected)

  output$dim<-renderUI({
    b<-colnames(data()[sapply(data(),class)=="character"])
    selectInput("x","Select only character variable",
                choices = b[1:length(b)],multiple = TRUE)
  })


  #  user selects levels of dimension 
  output$levels1<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$x)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else if(sum(input$x=="NONE")==1){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      mydata<-data()
      if(length(input$x)==2){
        selectInput(inputId = 'range1',
                    paste0("Select level of ",'category'),
                    choices = unique(as.character(mydata$category)),
                    selected = "",multiple = TRUE)
      } else {
        lapply(seq(input$x),function(i){
          mychoice<-unique(as.character(mydata[,input$x[i]]))
          selectInput(inputId = paste0("range",i),
                      paste0("Select level of ",input$x[i]),
                      choices = mychoice,selected = "",multiple = TRUE)
          })
      }
    }
  })

  output$level3<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$range1) | length(input$x)<2){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      mydata<-data()
      myrows<-grepl(paste0(input$range1,collapse = '|'),mydata$category)
      mychoices<-unique(as.character(mydata$Brand[myrows]))
      selectInput(inputId = 'range2',
                  paste0("Select level of ",'category'),
                  choices = mychoices,
                  selected = mychoices,multiple = TRUE)
    }

  })

  # Displaying Data  

  output$data_display <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$x)){ #show full data when nothing is selected in first dropdown
      mydata<-data()
    }
    if(is.null(input$range1)){ # show full data when nothing is selected in second drop down
      mydata<-data()
    } else { # something is selected in second dropdown
      if(length(input$x)>1){ # First dropdown contains two elements
        mydata<-data()
        if(!is.null(input$range2)){
          mydata=mydata[grep(paste0(input$range2,collapse='|'),as.character(mydata$Brand)),]
        }
      } else { # First dropdown contains one element
        mydata<-data()
        if(input$x=='Brand'){
          mydata=mydata[grep(paste0(input$range1,collapse='|'),as.character(mydata$Brand)),]
        } else{
          mydata=mydata[grep(paste0(input$range1,collapse='|'),as.character(mydata$category)),]
        }
      } # close: First dropdown has one element
    } # close: something is selected in second dropdown


    datatable(mydata,options = list(pageLength = 12),rownames = FALSE)
  })


  # observeEvent(input$x,
  #              updateSelectInput(inputId = paste0("range",i),
  #                                paste0("Select level of ",input$x[i]),
  #                                choices = unique(data()[,input$x])))

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```